# CSS Print Layout - Printing on a Single Page

Tags: html, printing, css, stylesheet

I'm badly stuck and the SO archives aren't helping me. Maybe I'm looking in the wrong place. Here's the short story:

- I've got a view that I need to get printed on a single full page. I can't have a second page and I need it to be as large as possible on the page.
- Solution has to be reasonably cross-browser compatible (IE9+, Safari, Chrome, FF).
- I already have a PDF solution, but I need a plain vanilla print solution as well.
- The page is built with Bootstrap, but I've overridden most of the classes for Print.

The structure of the HTML page is as follows. I dropped in some in-line CSS in order to customize some of this information.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span16">

      <style type="text/css" media="all">
        @media print {
          html, body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background: #FFF; 
            font-size: 9.5pt;
          }
          .container, .container div {
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
          }
          .template { overflow: hidden; }
          img { width: 100%; }
        }
      </style>

      <div class="template_holder">
        <div class="template">
          <img src="some_big_image">
          <div>
            [PLAIN TEXT IN HERE, POSITION:ABSOLUTE OVER THE IMAGE]
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I realize it's somewhat poor form to include in-line CSS here, but it has to override a bunch of other CSS that came before it for various reasons. I could pull it back out, but the gist of it is this. When I print, I get something that looks right, plus an extra second page. When I shrink the image down, everything is ok, but I need the image to fill the DIV.

I thought setting width to 100% was the issue, but I made sure the image aspect ratio was smaller than the page (even with any margins). Basically, the image at full width should not cause a page break. What am I doing wrong & what do I need to change? Any help is appreciated...

Comment: I think a diagram might help with visualizing your problem. I'm not sure what exactly the problem is at this point.

Comment: I don't know what I could diagram without adding complication. It's a 8.5"x11" piece of paper with an image inside it. I can't get it to print without creating an extra blank page (in Chrome and FireFox) when I size the image to 100% width.

Comment: Try setting it to like 95%. Try some value until it fits on one page. You could also try removing all margins and padding (e.g. `*{padding:0;margin:0}`). Also note that browser print a header and a footer, so the ratio of available space is not the same as the ratio of a blank page.

Comment: How can you be sure the piece of paper is 8.5"x11"?  How can you know what the actual printable area the printer is capable of is?  In short: how do you know you're not spending all this time over-optimizing for your particular printer and paper size rather than whatever your users will be using?

Comment: I am assuming Letter size paper. The issue happens before I even go to print. On Print Preview, I see 2 pages - the second one blank. @Gerben - setting it to 95% defeats the purpose of what I'm trying to do. The entire image appears currently, and I ensured Aspect Ratio was less than it would be for the page, even accounting for a full 1" margin. So there is no reason this should be printing a second blank page.

Comment: Print preview shows how something will print according to the current printer settings, once you're in print preview you've already gone to print.  Also, set the `img` to `display: block` so you're not trying to print the additional line height.

Comment: Thanks @robertc, I'll look into it. Trying to find an answer, but perhaps this is too specific a question for SO...

Comment: Note: Using bootstrap2.0 you might have used class="container-fluid", class="row-fluid", class="span12" for the respective 3 first divs. PS: there is no span16 class in bootstrap 2. Also at least in safari you will always get margins as borderless printing is not supported (the margin rules is ignored).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think the frustration with this detail of CSS is that the answer has to be tailored to my own project. Thanks to @blahdiblah and other for suggestions. A mix of solutions led to near-perfect results, though of course IE still gives me problems...

It had to do with a hard reset of all padding/margin styles and then lots of `!important` markers for padding, width, height, etc. Basically I filled up the page with height and then dropped in 100% wide objects. The result is maximum coverage on an 8.5x11 page with zero spillover to a second page.

```
@media print {
  * { margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important; }
  #controls, .footer, .footerarea{ display: none; }
  html, body {
    /*changing width to 100% causes huge overflow and wrap*/
    height:100%; 
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #FFF; 
    font-size: 9.5pt;
  }

  .template { width: auto; left:0; top:0; }
  img { width:100%; }
  li { margin: 0 0 10px 20px !important;}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your image is just too big.  Since the image is custom-sized, why not set

```
img { height: 100%; }
```

instead of `width`?  That would at least ensure that it didn't spill over to a second page.

Bear in mind also that printers are more variable than browsers.  You may be able to eke out every last inch of space on your printer, but someone else's might have significantly different print margins and ruin all your hard work.

Comment: I tried this. I'll re-post my latest attempts. It's still driving me crazy, because setting HTML & BODY to width:100% makes them wider than the page. Which is weird, I think. Height did some funky stuff too, but maybe that's the best way to go.