# What should be the height of a page/div so that it can fit to only a single page for the print?

Tags: html, css

I have a page with a just a header:

```
<body>
    <div class="page">
        <h1>This is the header</h1>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS is:

```
.page {
    height: 297mm;
    background-color: #0094ff;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

h1 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

When I try to print the page, the preview generates 2 pages. I just want it as a single page. So, what should be the height for the page class?

I just want the content to be printed on an A4 size page. How can I do it?

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8345857/css-print-layout-printing-on-a-single-page

Comment: Browsers tend to add a margin onto the html and/or body tags. If you force margin to 0px on those elements as well in your css, you might get the result you want.

Answer (score 2):

### Reset `margin`, `padding`, `height` of `html`, `body` elements

By zeroing out the margin and padding and setting the height to 100%, you'll achieve full page coverage (no more, no less).

```
    html, body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
    }
```

**Update:**

There is no need to specify a height for a particular page size in your CSS if you set the container element height to 100%.

If the page has more content than can fit on one printed page and you want to clip it, apply `height: 100%` and `overflow: hidden` to your container element — `.page` in this case.

```
.page {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #0094ff;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

If you want to apply padding to the `.page` element and maintain your single-page clipping, you will need to apply `box-sizing: border-box`.

```
.page {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 1em;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #0094ff;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the answer works well. But the issue occurs when i add several paragraphs and more header to the page. I want to fit my content to just a single page. If i know the fix height for the div that prints just on a single page, i can manage the margin,padding and line-height of the the content inside that div. If i add more 20 headers to the page div, only headers that fits on a single page should be visible. Others should be avoided due to overflow:hidden to page class. this height should be around 950px to 1050px varying browser to browser. I want to know that height for A4 size paper.

Comment: @SohilShah There is no need to specify a height for a particular page size in your CSS if you set the container element height to 100%. I have updated my answer with an example.